# AdMob SDK handle URL internally

Tags: iphone, ios, admob

I've integrated the AdMob SDK in my App, and I'm Using Google DFP for creating the Banners.

We produce some Ads what should be linked to internal Views. I've already implemented the handleOpenURL method, because in past we used another Ad System.

Adding custom HTML Code where I put a Link to my custom URL (example tab://MyView), then clicking on the Ad in my App, nothing succeed.

Is there a possibility to catch AdMob Url actions bevore they get redirected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AdMob has a feature for DFP called [App Events](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/dfp/fundamentals#ios_app-events) where your HTML ad creative can fire an event that the SDK will listen for - then you can implement

```
(void)adView:(DFPBannerView *)banner
    didReceiveAppEvent:(NSString *)name
              withInfo:(NSString *)info
```

and react accordingly.

To fire the event, you'll want to call `admob.events.dispatchEvent` from the [AdMob API for Ads](http://media.admob.com/api/v1/docs/) when the ad is clicked.